# Reactor. List of Monos, retry on fail

Tags: project-reactor, reactor

I have list `List<Mono<String>>`. Each Mono represents API call where I wait on I/O for result. The problem is that some times some calls return nothing (empty String), and I need repeat them again on that case.

Now it looks like this:

```
val firstAskForItemsRetrieved = firstAskForItems.map {
    it["statistic"] = (it["statistic"] as Mono<Map<Any, Any>>).block()
    it
}
```

I'm waiting for all Monos to finish, then in case of empty body I repeat request

```
val secondAskForItem = firstAskForItemsRetrieved
        .map {
            if ((it["statistic"] as Map<Any, Any>).isEmpty()) {
                // repeat request 
                it["statistic"] = getUserItem(userName) // return Mono
            } else
                it["statistic"] = Mono.just(it["statistic"])
            it
        }
```

And then block on each item again

```
val secondAskForItemsRetrieved = secondAskForItems.map {
    it["statistic"] = (it["statistic"] as Mono<Map<Any, Any>>).block()
    it
}
```

I see that looks ugly

- Are any other ways to retry call in Mono if it fails, without doing it manually?
- Is it block on each item a right way to get them all?
- How to make the code better?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 operators I believe can help your:

- For the "wait for all `Mono`" use case, have a look at the static methods `when` and `zip`.

  - `when` just cares about completion, so even if the monos are empty it will just signal an `onComplete` whenever all of the monos have finished. You don't get the data however.
  - `zip` cares about the values **and expects all Monos to be valued**. When all Monos are valued, it combines their values according to the passed `Function`. Otherwise it just completes empty.
- To retry the empty `Mono`s, have a look at `repeatWhenEmpty`. It resubscribes to an empty `Mono`, so if that `Mono` is "cold" it would restart the source (eg. make another HTTP request).

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive answer.